# Шрифты не срабатывают

Tags: шрифты, css

Подключаю шрифт таким образом.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'ElsieSwashCaps Regular';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('ElsieSwashCaps-Regular'), url(fonts/ElsieSwashCaps-Regular.ttf);
}
```

потом где необходим этот шрифт прописываю так

```
font-family: 'ElsieSwashCaps Regular', cursive;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@font-face {
  font-family: ElsieSwashCaps Regular;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('ElsieSwashCaps-Regular'), url(fonts/ElsieSwashCaps-Regular.ttf);
}
```

Comment: Кавычки роли не играют.

Answer (score 8):

Кроме .ttf, еще желательно .eot, .svg, .woff. Воспользуйтесь [онлайн-генератором](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator). Закидываете свой шрифт ttf - на выходе получаете весь набор. И уберите "local('ElsieSwashCaps-Regular')"